# how to deal with a strang jpgc format?

Tags: jpeg

I've been looking for some files through a working software to get some images. I found them but they were in .jpgc format, also for sounds they are in mp3c format.

As anyone I got the Idea to remove the "c" to obtain a normal jpg or mp3 format, but once I do this the files couldn't be read or edited by any software.

Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using somthing like the unix program like "file" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)  to identify the file contents type file type.
The tool is also available for windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm 
If the files are just "normal" .mp3 and .jpg files, you can just rename them from mp3c to mp3 and jpgc to jpg.